# Swipe back gesture with BottomNavBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using bottom navigation bar, and I need to push a view with bottom nav bar to be persistent.

And this is the main page:

```
MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
            pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
          TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
          TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
        })),
        home: Scaffold(
            body: IndexedStack(
              index: _pageIndex,
              children: const <Widget>[
                HomeView(),
                VideosSectionsView(),
                FavoritesView()
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                showBottomPlayer ? bottomPlayer(context) : Row(),
                const SizedBox(height: 0),
                bottomNavigationBar()
              ],
            )));
```

The problem is, when I push a view from HomeView to SecondView, and push again to ThirdView, the swipe back gesture from the ThirdView (in left edge of the screen) send me back to HomeView, but I want it to send me to SecondView (so *popping* only one view, not all the stack) do you know to achieve this?

For that I use CupertinoPageRoute:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: false).push(
    CupertinoPageRoute<bool>(
       fullscreenDialog: false, 
       builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondView()
    )
);
```

This is weird because if I set "*rootNavigator*" to true, it's working and I can pop only the last view of the stack, but the bottom nav bar is not persisted anymore in navigation !

So I have to chose between a good swipe back gesture or persisted nav bar ...

There's no problem with getting back programmatically :

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
```

So I want the same thing with Swipe Gesture, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

you can use pageView https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html. This is the example
https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded